# select rows and columns from all tables that have a column whose name begins with "TEST"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have multiple tables containing varying numbers of columns whose name begins with TEST:

Here is an example of what I would like to see if I were to execute the code:

```
TEST2UFLG TEST3UFLG TEST4UFLG TEST5UFLG TEST6UFLG 
--------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
0         1         0         1         0
... (rows elided)
0         1         0         1         0
```

This is the query that I have that returns the meta data that I would use to construct a query for each table that contains such columns.

```
select
  ( 
    select
      to_char(wm_concat(column_name)) 
    from
      dba_tab_columns 
    where
      owner = 'XXX' 
      and table_name = 'TBLXXXX' 
      and column_name like '%TEST%'
  )
from
  XXX.TBLXXXX
```

What I don't know is how to write the code that would use these data to generate the select statement (or statements) that would then be executed to return the rows I want.

Comment: Maybe someone can help you.  I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Since Oracle 9i there is [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm) but you need to use PL/SQL and not pure SQL. Is this what you require?

Comment: I read all your words, but I don't know what they mean. You start with "I have **a** table that lists..."  and then your next sentence is "Because **each** table contains..."  Are you even talking about the same tables? Please remember that no one is able to read another person's mind; we can only go by what you write down in words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create  a dynamic view

```
DECLARE
     v_select   CLOB;
BEGIN
     SELECT
          'SELECT '||LISTAGG(column_name,',')  
              WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id) ||' FROM ' || table_name
         INTO v_select
     FROM all_tab_columns 
        where owner = 'XXX' 
         and table_name = 'TBLXXXX' 
      and column_name like '%TEST%'
      group by table_name;
     IF
          v_select IS NOT NULL
     THEN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_testtbl as ' || v_select;
     END IF;
END;
/
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4acce760c2d741bc1cf6b07609cef2a6)